# cron chmod script does not change owner

Tags: bash, cron, chown

i need to run cron job that changes owner and group for selected files.

i have a script for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filez=`ls -la /tmp | grep -v zend | grep -v textfile | awk '$3 == "www-data" {print $8}'`
for ff in $filez; do
        /bin/chown -R tm:tm /tmp/$ff
done
```

if i run it manually - it works perfectly. if i add this to root's cron

```
* * * * *               /home/scripts/do_script
```

it does not change owner/group. file has permissions "-rwsr-xr-x".

any idea how this might be solved?

Comment: `chown` changes ownership, not permissions.

Comment: you need chmod ,also add your email to crontab to get any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, field `$8` is the hour/year, not the filename. Maybe that's the case for your root user as well. This is why you should never try to [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Even if you fix this issue, half a dozen more will remain to break the system in the future.

Use find instead:

```
find /tmp ! -name '*zend*' ! -name '*textfile*' -user www-data \
    -exec chown -R tm:tm {} \;
```

Comment: @michael It was supposed to be chown

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding to root's cron (/etc/crontab) then be aware that the syntax is different from a normal user's crontab.

```
# m h dom mon dow user      command
  * *  1   *   *  root      /usr/bin/selfdestruct --immediately
```

Also give the whole path to your command: Cron has not really a rich environment.
Make sure that the commands in your script also have the full path and don't use environment variables.